# API Assistance for oracle fusion financial 23c

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

"Greetings,

We are currently encountering issues in oracle fusion financial 23c . with  the input requirements for certain APIs. For instance, let's take a look at the following POST API:

API:- https://ehgt-test.fa.em2.oraclecloud.com/fscmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/erpintegrations .

```
JSON format:

{

"OperationName": "processTransaction-transferAsset",

"ParameterList": "{P_ASSET_ID:899124, P_BOOK_TYPE_CODE:BAE ASSET BOOK, P_DISTRIBUTION_ID_TBL: '410685',P_TRANSACTION_UNITS_TBL: 2,P_ASSIGNED_TO_TBL:'300100036762401', P_UNITS_ASSIGNED_TBL: 2, P_EXPENSE_CCID_TBL: '300100071633798', P_LOCATION_CCID_TBL: '300100071633793'}"

}
```

My question here is: What GET request can I use to retrieve the ID for a specific fixed asset, such as the Fixed Asset ID, IDP_location_CCID_TBL ID, or any related to expenses? I have thoroughly reviewed all available documentation, but unfortunately, I couldn't locate this information for use in my aforementioned POST request.."

we searched for get API but we could not find it .

Comment: Please put your Json content inside code block to make it more readable

Comment: Thank you for comment , now the code inside code bloc .